# Link list not sitting in container correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a bug in my CSS that I cant seem to fix. When I render the below code in my browser it puts the links in the header and footer on a new line (which subsequently makes the header and footer taller than they should be) and breaks the layout

http://tinkerbin.com/bhu0pfZF

How do I get the links to sit properly within their header/footer containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most tags have default margins and paddings, this should fix the problem:

```
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You may want to reset the others with:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked. I have this code in my CSS though, shouldnt this do the same? html, body {height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: Nope, that only sets it to the `html` and `body` tags. Try adding this: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` in your CSS. The `*` effects all tags. You can Google "CSS reset method" and you will find many different ways, the `*` is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some CSS Changes:

1. Remove `height: 60px;` and `line-height: 60px;` in `#header`.
2. Add `margin: 0;` for `#header ul`
3. Remove `height: 60px;` and `line-height: 60px;` in `#footer` and update `margin-top: -1.2em;`

#### Fiddle: http://tinkerbin.com/Gw7FiAIT